# Why does 'ls' recurse into folders?

Tags: bash, ls

Why does `ls` always recurse into folders when I use a wildcard on it (I'd rather that it didn't do this and instead just showed me all items in the directory starting with `m` and nothing else)?

```
$ ls
boot/  etc/   lost+found/  mnt/  proc/  run/  srv/  tmp/  var/  init*  lib32@  libx32@ dev/  home/  media/ opt/  root/  snap/  sys/  usr/  bin@  lib@   lib64@  sbin@

/ $ ls m*
media:

mnt:
c/  d/  e/  wsl/

$ alias ls
alias ls='ls -FAh --color=auto --group-directories-first'
```

Comment: You can use `ls -d m*`

Comment: This isn't a question about software development. It belongs on [unix.se], not here.

Comment: (I gather from context you're on Windows; _on Windows_ programs get access to their own command lines and are responsible for doing their own glob expansion, but that's not the case in UNIX-y platforms).

Comment: I'm on WSL, so it's real Linux (Ubuntu). Indeed, I probably should ask on Unix & Linux sorry for that, but I've already got great answers here, so I think I have good answers... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does ls always recurse into folders when I use a wildcard on it

It's according to the specifications if the wildcard globbing matches a directory.
From [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html):

> For each operand that names a file of type **directory**, `ls` shall write the names of files contained within the directory as well as any requested, associated information.

You can however override this default behavior by using the `-d` option:

> Do not follow symbolic links named as operands unless the `-H` or `-L` options are specified. Do not treat directories differently than other types of files. The use of `-d` with `-R` or `-f` produces unspecified results.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>This question is off-topic here, and should be migrated to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/); answering community-wiki for the OP's benefit, but expecting this to be closed).</sup>

---

`ls` **isn't** recursing. Instead, it's parsing the command line that it's given as an instruction to list the contents of the `media` directory.

---

The important thing to understand about UNIX in general is that commands don't parse their own command lines -- whatever starts a program is responsible for coming up with an array of C strings to be used as its command line argument, so a single string like `ls m*` can't be used.

The shell thus replaces `ls m*` with an array `["ls", "media"]` (when `media` is the only match for `m*`).

Because `ls` can't tell the difference between being given `media` as the name of a directory to list, and being given `media` as the result of expanding a glob, it assumes the former, and lists the contents of that directory.